# Do properties always have a value when unset?

Tags: c#, .net, properties

I have a property like this:

```
public Tuple<String, String>[] Breadcrumbs { get; set; }
```

and I have a test in one of my methods like this:

```
if (Breadcrumbs != null && Breadcrumbs.Length > 0) { }
```

Depending on when this method is called, `Breadcrumbs` may not have been set. In one test, `Breadcrumbs == null` evaulates to true.

Will unset properties always have a value? (Will it always be `null`?)

Answer (score 19, accepted):

An automatically-implemented property which hasn't been explicitly set by any code will always have the default value for the property type - which is null for reference types. (For `int` it would be 0, for `char` it would be '\0' etc).

An automatically implemented property like this is *just* equivalent to:

```
private PropertyType property;
public PropertyType Property
{
    get { return property; }
    set { property = value; }
}
```

... except that the backing variable has an unspeakable name (you can't refer to it in code) so it will always start off with the default value for the type.

Comment: extraterrestrial name hahahaha

Answer (score 3):

Auto-properties use backing fields and are compiled to regular properties.

If the Property-Type is a reference type the value would be null, if not the value would be the default value.

Answer (score 2):

Class member variables (called fields), and thus backing variables of properties, are always initialized to their default value, if they are not initialized explicitly, which is `null` for reference types. The default value for all types is the value whose binary representation consists of all bits set to 0.

On the other hand, C# requires you to initialize local variables explicitly. These are: variables declared in methods, constructors and property accessors and `out` method parameters; i.e. they are treated as undefined until you assign them a value.

Comment: Whoops, I've been coding C# up til now under the impression that I have to initialize everything or risk finding lots of random garbage. I think I'll keep up the habit though, so I don't make one of those terribly subtle mistakes when I drop back into C.

Comment: The C# compiler is good in detecting potentially uninitialized variables, so do not worry too much!

Comment: @Oliver: No, you will never find random garbage; the memory manager always initializes it. (In safe code; in unsafe code, you're on your own. That's why it's called "unsafe".) However, C# does require you to initialize all local variables explicitly before they are read from; this is not to prevent you from seeing garbage, it is to prevent you from writing bugs.

Comment: @EricLippert that said, I can't think of bugs in languages that don't insist on initialisation that are not either a) there's a default value set and the coder didn't expect it, leading to bug or b) there's random garbage there and the coder didn't expect it, leading to bug. A hypothetical C# that allowed use of uninitialised locals would have to lead to one or the other. (I'm guessing the former would cause too many verification problems too). Any other possibilities?

Answer (score 0):

It's logically impossible for it not to have a value. It's going to have to return something, some bunch of 1s and 0s that is at least believed to be a reference to a `Tuple<String, String>[]`, so to that extent it has a value.

It's also the case that all fields in classes get set to their default value (`default(T)` for whatever type `T` they are, which is `null` for all reference types). Otherwise it would be possible to have an object that was in a state that not only didn't make any sense in terms of what it does, but which didn't make any sense by the rules of what .NET expects objects to do. This includes the hidden fields behind automatic properties.

Now, in some languages we can do the equivalent of this:

```
public Tuple<String, String>[] Breadcrumbs
{
  get
  {
    Tuple<String, String>[] whatIWillSend;
    return whatIWillSend;
  }
}
```

If this were allowed, `whatIWillSend` would have a value defined not by any concious decision on your part, but by what happened to be in memory at the time. It could be null, it could be a valid `Tuple<String, String>[]` by sheer coincidence (but not the one you wanted to use!), it could be a `Dictionary<int, List<string>>` that the runtime is now going to think is actually a `Tuple<String, String>[]` (there goes the type-safety of the entire system), it could be a quarter of a `decimal` structure. (In the languages that allow such things, it could also be a well-known value that debuggers for such languages set in these cases precisely so to help find bugs caused by it).

That's the closest thing we can get to a property not having a value. Note though that:

1. It would still have a value, just not a meaningful value.
2. We aren't allowed to do this in C# anyway.